# Email Extractor Java Pattern excluding characters before a dot

Tags: java, regex, email, pattern-matching, extractor

I am currently using an email extractor which is working well, but I would like to change its pattern which is:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-](?<num>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,20}@[A-Za-z0-9_-]{3,20}\.[\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

The problem with this pattern is that it excludes all the charaters before a dot.

For example, if it finds an email like **"john.smith@gmail.com"**, it will report **"smith@gmail.com"**

I don't know what I should write in the pattern so it does not exclude the characters before the dot anymore.

If someone has an idea, please let me know... many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right, try this regex:

```
\b(?<num>[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]{2,20}@[\w-]{3,20}\.[.\w-]+)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ9oO3/2)

Comment: His regex has a caret (`^`) in that first character class. Yours doesn't. I prefer your `\b` but then you should get rid of that entire character class. Right now it misses out the first letter of any email address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried, it's working really well!